# Using MS Graph API, can we able to get cross domain data

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I would love to know, using MS Graph API can I able to get data from cross-domain. For Example, I have a tenant called "**Tenant A**" and another tenant called "**Tenant B**". Is there any possible way to get some site usage details from "Tenant A" and store that data as a CSV or Excel in "Tenant B" using power automate?

Note: Without coding.

Answer (score 0):

From [this power automate forum thread](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Transfering-data-between-Tenants/m-p/468957#M45841), it is possible by having two accounts and creating flows using each credentials, one in each tenant but it obviously has security implications.

Also, it probably means you will need to register apps in both tenants.